# Spark Scala code failing with exitCode -1073741515 while writing file

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, intellij-idea

I am getting below Error while trying to run simple program with spark scala in IntelliJ
Error:

```
Caused by: ExitCodeException exitCode=-1073741515:
```

Code:

```
file.saveAsTextFile("out/output.txt")
```

Environment:
Using Below SW/Versions
Java - 1.8.0_322
Scala - 2.12.10
Spark - 3.0.3 with hadoop 2.7

HADOOP_HOME, JAVA_HOME and SPARK_HOME are set accordingly.

winutils.exe and hadoop.dll are present at C:\winutils

Gradle Entry: `implementation 'org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.12:3.0.3'`

Comment: Provide stacktrace please.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried downloading and installing Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Service Pack 1 Redistributable Package from the Official Microsoft Download Center?

https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=26999

Comment: In our org I can see only below versions available for installation -

Comment: In our org I can see only below versions available for installation. Cant find 2010. Can I use any of this ?  Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable 8.0.61001
Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable 2.0
Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable 14.x
Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable 12.X
Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable 11.0.x
Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable 11.0